# Identify the participant invoking a transaction on composer-rest-server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to identify the user invoking a transaction through the API generated from the composer-rest-server in Hyperledger Composer?

Is it possible to generate a Token when authenticating on the Composer REST server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to enable authentication on the REST server, suggest the following doc, https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html, this will provide the token you are looking for.

Once you have an auth strategy enabled (github, google, etc.) for your REST server you can following the 'Adding a Blockchain identity to the default wallet' section from the following doc, https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html

As the title suggests, these steps highlight managing a wallet of identities, which is tied to a Composer participant.  With the identities in place you can use the API endpoint of GET /system/ping to determine the Composer participant who is issuing the transactions.

Comment: how do I get that user identity inside the transaction that is being invoked?